Merge and create tags using Jenkins
I have created a (Freestyle with windows batch command) job that gives user the option to select the sprint branch and merge it with Master.
In bitbucket, the master job has some branch - level restrictions to a specific set of users (part of Administrators group). When i run the job, I get permission denied at the time of git push. However, when I remove the branch level restriction, it works fine.
Hence I suspect that the branch restriction on bitbucket is the issue.
Following is the setup:
The user who has push access Branch restriction to master : devops@mydomain.com and is a part of the "Administrators" group who has full access to master
Basis the above email, can you please let me know:

How should I create the SSH key and where should I keep the same on the devops server?
With what user id should i create the shhk key in bitbucket?
How should I map the same in Jenkins

I have made a lot of googling, but can make it through.
Hence would appreciate your help.
Regards
Pratik
The job shoukd run perfectly with branch retrictions

First login into your Jenkins server and switch to Jenkins user using below command
su -s /bin/bash Jenkins

Then execute the below commands in the bash shell, to generate SSH key pair and display the key
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 

Now login in bitbucket as user devops@mydomain.com.
Go to Personal Settings > SSH Keys and add the key.
Now in Jenkins, go to Manage Jenkins > Manage Credentials.
Add a new SSH Username with private key credential:
Username: devops@mydomain.com
Private Key: Paste the key

Use this credential while connecting the bitbucket in the freestyle Jenkins job

Hello Rahul, Thank you very much for your reply.  I have a windows server and dnt have bash. Is there any other alternative (like command prompt) . Is Jenkins  (in su command) a keyword or in - built user name?. Secondly when i create ssh-keygen, for which account will it create?

you can use powershell terminal or a command prompt instead. 'jenkins' is a default user created when you install Jenkins on a server. you just need to switch to jenkins user and perform the action of key generation. once generated the ssh keys will be stored in below location
C:\Users\jenkins.ssh
remember one thing, in
id_rsa file: The private key is stored.
id_rsa.pub file: The public key is stored.

It would be great if u can help me with a step by step process. My bitbucket userid is devops@mydomain.com and my Jenkins user id is devopsmydomain (and also the same user name in my windows server). By any chance is there a relation between the Jenkins user id, bitbucket user id and windows user id?

Hello Rahul, Jenkins is installed on ther server, but i can see any user with the name "jenkins" in c:\users folder of my jenkins server. When checked in jenkins configuration, I see the follwoing : C:\Users\devopsmydomain\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins

First Install OpenSSH.
Open Command Prompt as Administrator and run:
runas /user:devopsmydomain cmd
Now Generate an SSH Key Pair for Jenkins User
ssh-keygen -t rsa
The key will be stored in C:\Users\devopsmydomain.ssh. Remember
id_rsa: The private key.
id_rsa.pub: The public key.
Now login in bitbucket as user devops@mydomain.com. Go to Personal Settings > SSH Keys and add the public key.
Now in Jenkins, go to Manage Jenkins > Manage Credentials. Add a new SSH Username with private key credential:
Username: devops@mydomain.com
Private Key: Paste the private key

Hello Rahul, It did not worked. Got the same error : remote: Permission denied to update branch master. I followed the same instruction as you had elaborated above (on 28th August). Just a note: I DID NOT INSTALLED OPENSSH.

First ensure that the correct SSH key is being used in Jenkins by running the following test from the Jenkins server:
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
You should see a message like:
authenticated via ssh key associated with 'devops@mydomain.com'
If you see a different user or an error, Jenkins is using the wrong key.

Also you can use the Bitbucket API to check if the user associated with the SSH key actually has the required permissions to push to the master branch, use below command for it:
curl -u devops@mydomain.com:YOUR_BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/your_workspace/your_repo/refs/branches/master/permissions
